# Image Carousel Interval Issue

Tags: javascript, carousel

**Hello #Peeps,**
I am creating one application in javascript,I am facing one issue when my state code (i.e 1,2,3,4) change at that time image interval not affected.

**In Details:**
   I have 2 states (i.e Active state and idle state)
   Code of active state is 1 and code of idle state are 2
   In the active state, there are 3 images each image have an interval of 1000(1     sec),2000(2sec),3000(3 sec) respectively.
   Same images interval in an idle state.
   I am using image carousel javascript

```
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
   }

   slideIndex++;

   if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
   x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
   setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

But when my state code auto update at that time my image specific interval didn't work, image timeout take an uneven interval and skip some images.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much nicer to use interval and have that set outside the function. Like this.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slideIndex++;

  slideIndex > x.length && (slideIndex = 1);
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}

setInterval(function() {
  carousel()
}, 2 * 1000); // Change image every 2 seconds
```

```css
.mySlides {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 140px;
}
.mySlides:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
.mySlides:nth-child(2) {
  background: tomato;
}
.mySlides:nth-child(3) {
  background: pink;
}
.mySlides:nth-child(4) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="mySlides">1</div>
<div class="mySlides">2</div>
<div class="mySlides">3</div>
<div class="mySlides">4</div>
```

In this demo, it keeps at the 2-second pace.
Hope this helps.